# Is it more efficient to hold down R2 or repeatedly click when shooting in Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront

If I am in a 1v1 battle with someone in Star Wars Battlefront, I usually hold own the right trigger. If I pressed and released frequently instead of holding my finger down, would that increase the efficiency?

Comment: I've never played it, but it would probably at least increase your accuracy. Weapons tend to get less accurate when not fired in short bursts.

Comment: @Robotnik, not as much, in battlefront.Instead, they overheat, and require you to wait or succeed a quick time event, to continue. Preference usually depends on the player and their ability

Comment: You also have to consider the slight amount of auto-aim this game has and I feel there really is no difference.  Whatever that feels more natural to you I guess.

Comment: Depends which battlefront you mean. In the first two tap-firing produced better accuracy without a firerate penalty, while in the new one I couldn't say as I haven't really played it enough to give a definite answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your weapon. If you have a rapid fire blaster like a pistol, it would make sense to hold down R2 (but only until your gun is near overheating). For guns like the shock blaster and ranged weapons, intermittent fire is probably best - in the former case, you'll use up your limited ammo too quickly, and for longer range, heavy guns, you want to be able to adjust your line of fire to track distant moving targets more easily.